# Flashdata is not cleared after a redirect in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-flashdata

I'm using CodeIgniter 3 and the flashdata I set on that project is not cleared even after a redirect. It still being shown after the page is refreshed or visit the page again. How can I fix this issue?

A function in a controller.

```
public function updateDonor($donor)
    {

        $birthDate = $this->input->post('donordob');
        $currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
        $age = date_diff(date_create($birthDate), date_create($currentDate));

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('donorname', 'Donor Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('donornic', 'Donor NIC', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('donordob', 'Donor DOB', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('donorweight', 'Donor Weight', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('donormobile', 'Donor Mobile', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $data = [
                'DonorName' => $this->input->post('donorname'),
                'DonorNIC' => $this->input->post('donornic'),
                'DonorDOB' => $this->input->post('donordob'),
                'DonorAge' => $age->format("%y"),
                'DonorWeight' => $this->input->post('donorweight'),
                'DonorMobile' => $this->input->post('donormobile'),
            ];
            $this->load->model('Donor_Model');
            $data['donor'] = $this->Donor_Model->updateDonor($data, $donor);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('donorupdated', 'Donor detailed updated successfully!');
            redirect(base_url('index.php/staff/viewdonors'));
        } else {
            $this->editDonors($donor);
        }


    }
```

Code in the view

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('donorupdated')) { ?>
    <script>
        alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'top-right');
        alertify.success("<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('donorupdated'); ?>")
    </script>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `unset($_SESSION['donorupdated']);` after the `<script>` tag like below

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('donorupdated')) { ?>
    <script>
        alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'top-right');
        alertify.success("<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('donorupdated'); ?>")
    </script>
    <?php unset($_SESSION['donorupdated']); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not do this please follow the following steps.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then inside `autoload.php`
add `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`

For your kind reference please have a look [Session Library](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html)

Then inside `config.php`.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Code in view

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('donorupdated')) { ?>
    echo $this->session->flashdata('donorupdated');
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Amit can you explain where should I write the `create table` code. Should I create a new table in the DB?

Comment: Yes. You have to create the table named **ci_sessions**  in your MySQL database.

Comment: I tried this solution but the flashdata is still not cleared after a redirect.

Comment: You can solve your problem in the following way.  
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('donorupdated')) { ?>
    echo $this->session->flashdata('donorupdated');
    unset($_SESSION['donorupdated']);
    <?php } ?>